# PySpark map multiple columns to 1 'dict' column containing all values without using df.collect()

Tags: pyspark

I currently have multiple columns (at least 500) in my DataFrame starting with any of the following prefixes ['a_', 'b_', 'c_'].

I want to have a DataFrame with only 3 columns

```
#  +++++++++++++++++++++
#    a  |  b  |  c  |
#  +++++++++++++++++++++
#  {'a_1': 'a_1_value', 'a_2': 'a_2_value'} | {} | {'c_1': 'c_1_value', 'c_2': 'c_2_value'}|
```

Calling df.collect() causes StackOverflowErrors in the framework I'm using because the DataFrame is pretty large. I'm trying to leverage the map functions to avoid loading the DataFrame in the driver (hence the constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

Use `struct` to combine any columns with a certain prefix into 1 column, then use `to_json` to form the `struct` into key-value pair shape.

```py
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df.select([
    F.to_json(F.struct(*[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith(f'{col}_')])).alias(col)
    for col in cols]
)
```